# Possible to find the line or position where an error happens?

Tags: debug, backtrace

With stack traces in elisp, I only see the function and the error that occurred within this function.

Is it possible to also include the line number or the character-position where the error took place?

It's often not enough information to track down the issue easily, and I end up adding print's in the code or splitting out functions for the purpose of knowing where the error is - which is quite inconvenient.

Comment: Functions have no notion of line number or char position. Don't think source code; think functions. Imagine that everything is byte-compiled, for example.

Comment: You can instrument the function that produces the error using e.g. `edebug`: that's frequently quicker and easier than adding `print`s.

Comment: @NickD I've never used edebug, could this be made into an answer?

Comment: Not without duplicating the [Edebug documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Edebug.html), but basically you instrument the function(s) of interest, set breakpoints at the places where you want to check, continue to the next breakpoint and use `e` to evaluate variables or expressions.